# getting Error Code: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a procedure -

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `genome`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `get_family`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_family`(p_h INT(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children VARCHAR(1024);
    DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;

        SET rv = '';
    SET queue = p_h;
    SET queue_length = 1;

    WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
        SET front_id = FORMAT(queue,0);

        IF queue_length = 1 THEN
            SET queue = '';
        ELSE
            SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
            SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
            SET queue = q;
        END IF;
        SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;

        SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
        FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) qc
        FROM folder WHERE parent = front_id) A;

        IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue_length = 0;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                SET rv = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                SET queue = queue_children;
            ELSE
                SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;

   SELECT rv FROM DUAL;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It succeeded, but when I am calling the proc, it gives me error -

```
call get_family(117);
Error Code: 1292
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '118,119,120,124'
```

But when i am passing the same 116 in the procedure, its working fine.
Where i am doing wrong. Please let me know.

Comment: does it give you a line number for where this error occurs? i'm guessing it's where you have `SELECT INTO ... GROUP_CONCAT()`. If the `qc` field in queue_children is a double field, you're trying to stuff a bunch of comma-separated numbers in there, which is a string, not a double.

Comment: @MarcB - no its not giving me any line number. and queue_children is a varchar type. But if it is running against 116 id then why not against 117? is there any way i can cast datatype if it is a problem?

Comment: the big question is where is this `118,119,120,124` csv line coming from? That's where you're getting a string, and somewhere you're trying to stuff that string into a double.

Comment: @MarcB B - ok so is there any way that i can perform casting on every doubtful column? i copy this procedure which was actually a function, if you can see here.. because i dont have reputation to comment there :( 
    http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-    of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes/7161#7161

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution.

I simply changed the varchar(output was long i think) type to text on the top, now its working properly.