# MySQL stored procedure doesn't work, error says "Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value", error occur on MySQL 5.6.12, but the same works on 5.6.19

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `ROUTINE_CHECK_POLICY`(P_USERID INT(11), P_PRIV_ID INT, P_CUSTID INT(10), OUT F_FINAL_DEVICE_LIST varchar(600))
BEGIN

DECLARE F_USER_GROUP_LIST VARCHAR(300);

SELECT group_concat(concat(USER_USERGROUP_GROUP_ID) separator ',') INTO F_USER_GROUP_LIST
FROM   TBL_STD_USER_USERGROUP
where  USER_USERGROUP_USER_ID = P_USERID
AND    USER_USERGROUP_CUSTID  = P_CUSTID;

END
```

when i execute above stored procedure as below
call ROUTINE_CHECK_POLICY(1,3,1,@outparam);
it says error: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

```
Table TBL_STD_USER_USERGROUP have field USER_USERGROUP_USER_ID and USER_USERGROUP_CUSTID as int(11)
```

Comment: although the issue solved as refereed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865735/getting-error-code-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value-in-stored-procedure
but, was that due to MySQL version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the solution.

I simply changed the `varchar`(output was long I think) type to `text` on the top, now its working properly.