# MySQL: Triggers leading to Error 1292 (truncated incorrect DOUBLE value) when inserting?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Can you help me resolve the error 'Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value' (Error Code 1292) in MySQL 6.3? I've searched for a solid hour and can't find a suitable answer in all the similar questions:

My task is to insert triggers into a database of movies. If someone tries to update an existing value or insert a new value into the schema 'made_money', then it is to be assured that the category falls into one of four base categories (see code). If it doesn't, default to "Action". I built and executed two triggers for this (because I don't know how to put UPDATE and INSERT into a single trigger):

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER movie_categories_A BEFORE UPDATE ON made_money
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Category NOT IN ("Romantic", "Comedy", "Drama", "Action") THEN
        SET NEW.Category = "Action";
    END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER movie_categories_B AFTER INSERT ON made_money
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF Category NOT IN ("Romantic", "Comedy", "Drama", "Action") THEN
        SET Category = "Action";
    END IF;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

Also, a new entry into 'log_data' has to be made when a new value is inserted into 'made_money', containing only the 'Movie' and 'Category' values.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER condensed_test AFTER INSERT ON made_money
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log_data
        SET Movie = NEW.Movie AND Category=NEW.Category;
END;//
delimiter ;
```

The three triggers all executed, although I'm not sure whether they are erroneous. Now my task is to insert a new entry into 'made_money':

```
INSERT INTO made_money (MOVIE,HOW_MUCH,DAY_OPENED,Category)
VALUES ('Iron Man', 1000000, '2008-05-02', 'ACTON');
```

I know that 'ACTON' is misspelled (I guess this is part of the exercise), yet unfortunately, this results in the following error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Iron Man'
```

The same happens if I spell 'Action' correctly. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Best,
Jan

Comment: Can you post the table schema for `made_money`?  I would guess `movie` is not a `varchar` based on the error...

Comment: [link]http://oi66.tinypic.com/68e9a8.jpg
It is a varchar(50).

Comment: Try changing varchar to text, and it will be done

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't easy, as movie is a primary key. This means that I'd have to drop and re-enter it in order to change the type (according to StackOverflow answers on how that works). But other foreign keys rely on it and I don't know which ones and I'd rather not drop these connections.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments. I was able to resolve the issue, however not through changing the data type as suggested in the answers, but by changing the second trigger from "AFTER insert on" to "BEFORE insert on" and by changing the insertion syntax of the third trigger to "insert into log_data (Movie,category) values (new.movie,new.Category);". Thank you all the same!
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Try to change datatype for `Movie`, try by making it `Text`, 
you can refer [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209058/mysql-stored-procedure-doesnt-work-error-says-truncated-incorrect-double-valu/34193370#34193370)

Comment: @Jan Luba: Please let me know if its works by changing datatype to `Text`

Answer (score 0):

- Please check the datatype 'made_money.Movie' and 'log_data.Movie'.
- Please check the collation.